# JavaFX webview in Arduino ide custom tool

Tags: plugins, javafx, webview, arduino, processing

I am trying to create a Google Blockly tool for the arduino ide. The tool makes it easy for kids to program the Dwenguino microcontroller board by using graphical programming.

I am implementing my tool in Java using the JavaFX WebView. Everyting works fine when i run my tool as a standalone Java application but when I start it through the tools menu in the arduino ide, the WebView is unable to load the linked css and JavaScript files specified in the header of my index.html file.

I should mension that, right now, the html, javascript and css files are included into my .jar file. I do this because I want the users to be able to install the plugin by puting the jar into the right arduino plugin folder.

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:processing]. Does it have anything to do with the [Processing language](https://www.processing.org/)?

Comment: The arduino IDE is based on the Processing IDE, they have the same plugin system.

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post a [mcve] along with your question.